# Programmatically Retrieve OSX Network/Proxies configuration values

Tags: macos, cocoa, http-proxy

Considering my application has the user ID and Password for the admin user currently logged in, is it possible to retrieve the configuration values from the OSX Network settings? Particularly interested in the "Advanced/Proxies" tab content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did it with the settings API. Here's an example to fetch the PAC URL string from the OSX Network Settings.

```
static char url[257] = {0};

NSDictionary * proxies = (NSDictionary *)SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(NULL);
NSString * pacURL = [proxies objectForKey:(NSString *)kSCPropNetProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString];

if (NULL != pacURL)
{
    strncpy((char*) (&(url)[0]), 
            [pacURL cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],
            sizeof(url));
}
return url;
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the `scutil` command.  In particular, `scutil --proxy` will show the proxies

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a programmatic way from a Cocoa application.