# Retrieving Mac OS X Proxy IP address

Tags: c, macos

I'm trying to programmatically get the proxy IP address or URL set on a system.
I found code that might work in a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327582/programmatically-retrieve-osx-network-proxies-configuration-values), but it's in Objective-C and what I am trying to use is plain C.

I've tried translating that obj-c code to C but no success.

Anyone knows how to get the system proxy in C?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a C translation of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327582/programmatically-retrieve-osx-network-proxies-configuration-values/4368198#4368198):

```
CFDictionaryRef proxies = SCDynamicStoreCopyProxies(NULL);
if (proxies) {
    CFStringRef pacURL = (CFStringRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(proxies,
        kSCPropNetProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString);

    if (pacURL) {
        char url[257] = {};
        CFStringGetCString(pacURL, url, sizeof url, kCFStringEncodingASCII);
        // do something with url
    }

    CFRelease(proxies);
}
```

It needs to be linked to two frameworks: SystemConfiguration and CoreFoundation.

Note that this code gets the URL for automatic proxy configuration (`kSCPropNetProxiesProxyAutoConfigURLString`), if any. There are several other possible proxies, e.g. HTTP proxy or HTTPS proxy. For a list of all possible proxies, see the [SCSchemaDefinitions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SCSchemaDefinitions/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Thank you, let me try it. I know how to set the automatic proxy config, but how do I set the HTTP proxy? Via the browser? The command line?

Comment: @MrA Via System Preferneces > Network > Advanced… > Proxies > Web Proxy (HTTP).